# Keeping the same gap while resizing buttons

Tags: css

I have two buttons that appear side by side. The idea is that whenever the screen width changes, the buttons will grow or shrink accordingly. This is working fine. However, I'd like to have a 10px distance between the buttons, no matter what the screen width is. In my case as the screen width grows, the gap also grows which I'd like to avoid.

Here is the test code I have been working with:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
body {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
}
div.buttons {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0 5px;
}
a.left, a.right {
    display: block;
    width: 49%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #f00;
    text-align: center;
}
a.left {
    float: left;
}
a.right {
    float: right;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="buttons">
<a class="left" href="">One</a>
<a class="right" href="">Two</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I can tell that giving a 1% to the gap will make it grow with the screen, but I'm trying to find a way of giving the gap a fixed size while having the button behave as expected.

EDITED TO ADD: I'm looking for a solution which not only would keep the gap fixed but that will also keep the left and right margins fixed as well. So 5px space to edge, button, 10px gap, button, 5px space to edge.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Why don't you use bootstrap for this? Your results will likely look better. http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: Did you receive an acceptable answer?

Comment: Sorry, had some health problems which kept me away from work. Will go through all the answers now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dux0xd3o/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="buttons">
  <div class="button-container">
    <a class="button">first</a>
  </div><div class="button-container">
    <a class="button">second</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.buttons {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
}
.button-container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.button {
   display: block;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   background-color: #f00;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 5px;    
}
.button-container:nth-child(odd) .button {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.button-container:nth-child(even) .button {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Key points to take home. Firstly, you need to avoid any whitespace between the inline-block elements `.button-container` to avoid a rendered space. Otherwise, setting `width:50%` will end up wrapping (because your have two 50% wide items with an intervening space, which is more that 100% width). Secondly, using .button-container allows you to evenly split the buttons across the page using a set percentage. The spacing between buttons then becomes a margin **interior** to the container.

Answer (score 0):

That's due to the fact that you links are aligned to the outer borders (via float), not to each other. To change it the way you want, remove the floats and center them, plus add a 10px margin-right on the left one:

(for the snippet I reduced the width to 48% since otherwise it won't fit into a small screen)

```css
body {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
}
div.buttons {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
a.left, a.right {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 48%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #f00;
    text-align: center;
}
a.left {
 margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
<a class="left" href="">One</a>
<a class="right" href="">Two</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Johannes. The problem is that now the gap is fixed but the space between the buttons and the edges increases as the screen grows (I should have mentioned I'm trying to find a way to keep all spaces fixed and have only the button widths grow).

Comment: note my second answer. I hope you didn't forget anything else ;-)

Answer (score 0):

So here's a new version, fulfilling your later added additional requirements.

It gives the buttons absolute position and defines their width by defining their left and right borders 5px from the outer border and 5px each from the center (adding up to a 10px distance between them), using `calc`:

```css
body {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
}
div.buttons {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1.6em;
}
a.left, a.right {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    background-color: #f00;
    text-align: center;
}
a.left {
 left: 5px;
 right: calc(50% + 5px);
}
a.right {
 right: 5px;
 left: calc(50% + 5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
<a class="left" href="">One</a>
<a class="right" href="">Two</a>
</div>
```